# cfparam order of attribute execution

Tags: coldfusion

Is there documentation on the order in which the attributes of the cfparam are executed. I am using regex to identify the pattern of a value coming from a spreadsheet but I would like to verify the length of the string first to prevent unnecessary regex processing. For example if the value should be no longer than 10 characters and one is 11 the regex does not run.

Can I use one cfparam or is it better to use two? One to check the length then if that passes then execute the regex.

```
 <cfparam name="columnValue" type="regex" pattern="^[a-9]+" maxLength="3">

 <cfparam name="columnValue" type="any" maxLength="3">
 <cfparam name="columnValue" type="regex" pattern="^[a-9]+">
```

Comment: Perhaps you should read the documentation on cfparam to see what it actually does.

Comment: or just test it and see how it works. By the way, you can also check length using regex.  Something like `^[a-9]{1,3}+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you're trying to do, instead of getting hung up on how to make those attributes work, I'd rather just do this - much simpler

```
<!--- get the param value --->
<cfparam name="columnValue" default="[if needed]">

<!--- if length less than and REFind or REFindNoCase, based on requirements --->
<cfif len(columnValue) LT [whatever] AND REFind([reg exp], [your string])> 
    .....
</cfif>
```

Comment: I used something similar. Thanks.